Drawing surfaces with TikZ
As a complete TikZ novice, I want to create surfaces like the following handdrawn one with TikZ:

Ideally, this should be coded bottom-up: First you draw the bident with xy-plane at height 0. Then you draw a straight line at a higher height (This line is not visible in the drawing, it lies in between the height of the two purple vertices). Then you draw a bident at an even higher height. Finally, you fill in the vertical (and the thicker) lines.
I tried using code like this:
\begin{tz}[td, scale=2]

\begin{scope}[xyplane=0]
\draw (-1,0) to [bend left=15] (0.5,1) to (1.8,3);
\draw (0,-0.3) to [bend right=15] (0.5,1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xyplane=0.25*\h]
\draw(-0.5,0) to (1.4,3);
\end{scope} 

\begin{scope}[xyplane=0.5*\h]
\draw (-0.5,0) to (1.3,3);
\end{scope} 

\begin{scope}[xyplane=0.75*\h]
\draw (-1,0) to [bend left=15] (0.5,1) to (1.8,3);
\draw (0,-0.3) to [bend right=15] (0.5,1);
\end{scope}

\end{tz}

However, I am having trouble with the following:

draw the vertical lines
draw jagged lines
draw the curved thick lines (one in black, one in green)
draw the dotted edge that is hidden behind a face as dotted
"colour" faces by a transparent "colour"

How can I draw the above surface efficiently with TikZ? Can this be done with TikZiT?

What defines the type of curvature of the surfaces leaving the plane? Do you have an equation?

@jessexknight: What do you mean by "type of curvature"? I don't have an equation, and would not want to use one to create the surface. Using an equation does seem tedious, especially for surfaces more complicated than the above.

Well, you will need something to specify the rounded surface. Maybe a part of a sphere will work here, but some diagram drawers have an underlying function they are illustrating, so I thought I'd ask

Please provide code people can compile. What defines tz?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{40}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords, decoration={random steps, segment length=0.5pt, amplitude=0.3pt}, line join=round]
\coordinate (A) at (-1,0,-1);
\coordinate (B) at (-1,0,1);
\coordinate (C) at (0.8,0,1);
\coordinate (D) at (0.8,0,-1);
\path (C) +(0,-0.3,0) coordinate (Cl);
\path (C) +(0,0.3,0) coordinate (Cr);
\path (C) +(-0.8,0,0) coordinate (Cb);
\path (C) +(0,0,-0.8) coordinate (Cd);
\path (D) +(0,-0.3,0) coordinate (Dl);
\path (D) +(0,0.3,0) coordinate (Dr);
\path (D) +(-0.8,0,0) coordinate (Db);
\path (D) +(0,0,0.6) coordinate (Du);
\draw[green!70!black, ultra thick, canvas is xz plane at y=0] (Cb) to[bend right] (Cd);
\draw[ultra thick, canvas is xz plane at y=0] (Db) to[bend left] (Du);
\draw[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5]
[canvas is xz plane at y=0] (A) -- (B) -- (Cb) to[bend right] (Cd) decorate{-- (Du)} to[bend right] (Db) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5]
{[canvas is xz plane at y=0] (Cb) to[bend right] (Cd)}
decorate{[canvas is yz plane at x=0.8] (Cd) to[bend right] (Cr)}
{[canvas is xy plane at z=1] -- (Cr) to[bend right] (Cb)};
\draw[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5]
{[canvas is xz plane at y=0] (Db) to[bend left] (Du)}
decorate{[canvas is yz plane at x=0.8] (Du) to[bend left] (Dr)}
{[canvas is xy plane at z=-1] -- (Dr) to[bend right] (Db)};
\draw[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5]
{[canvas is xz plane at y=0] (Cb) to[bend right] (Cd)}
decorate{[canvas is yz plane at x=0.8] (Cd) to[bend left] (Cl)}
{[canvas is xy plane at z=1] -- (Cl) to[bend left] (Cb)};
\draw[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.5]
{[canvas is xz plane at y=0, , opacity=0.5] (Db) to[bend left] (Du)}
decorate{[canvas is yz plane at x=0.8] (Du) to[bend right] (Dl)}
{[canvas is xy plane at z=-1] -- (Dl) to[bend left] (Db)};
\fill[purple!80!black] (Cd) circle[radius=1pt] (Du) circle[radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Excellent!!! Can you do some tex code with TikZ for me? :-)

Yes - sure. If it is interesting and I see your question first, I will do it. If it is something bigger - do it for me type of job, I will need payment.

I would to learn Adobe Illustrator. With TiKZ I lost many times. My best regards.
